# Secondary indexes vs Using elastic search

Tags: database-design, index, elasticsearch

When does it make sense to put data in elastic search vs creating secondary indexing on Primary datastore?
Elastic search with another primary store

Pros:

1. Primary datastore can be optimised for read write usecases.
2. Elastic search suports more than just key value matching like fuzzy match, etc.

Cons:

1. Out of sync with primary datastore
2. two more component to manage (ES as well a pipeline to insert in ES)
3. Would need some sort of Change data capture capability from Primary datastore.

Secondary indexes on Primary datastore

Pros:

1. Less moving parts.
2. Less consistency issues ( because secondary indexes can be eventually consistant)

Cons

1. Not all datastore support secondary indexing
2. Secondary index queries are more oftan scatter gather, doing it on higher QPS will limit read write qps on primary access patterns like read, write by PK

Are there other considerations while deciding this?

Answer (score 2):

> When does it make sense to put data in elastic search vs creating secondary indexing on Primary datastore?

These things are like comparing apples to oranges.

Use Elasticsearch when your **primary** use case is complex word based searching and / or large bodies of text that need to be tokenized into words that are easily searchable.

Otherwise, for most other standard use cases, you'll probably want to use a relational database system (RDBMS). In an RDBMS, sometimes the primary index (usually referred to as clustered index) of a table is sufficient. Other times a secondary index (or a few secondary indexes) are needed to support the predicate use cases. It's very common to create secondary indexes, when needed.

In regards to some other things you mentioned:

> Elastic search with another primary store
>
> Pros:
>
> 1. Primary datastore can be optimised for read write usecases.

Not sure what you mean by this. Elasticsearch won't automatically be any faster at reading and writing operations itself. And if you mean the read / writes of the source data store would be improved by offloading some of the work to Elasticsearch, that's not necessarily true either unless you use an eventual consistency methodology to copy the data over. Also, in that case, it has nothing to do with using Elasticsearch, and more so just the fact you're persisting a copy of the data, which can be done in any other system including another instance of the same source system.

> 2. Elastic search suports more than just key value matching like fuzzy match, etc.

Elasticsearch is designed to be **optimized** at complex word based searching, as I mentioned earlier. It is **not as optimized** at standard key-value matching, and classic index seeking for equality and range matches, as an RDBMS is. Again, different use cases that both systems are optimized for and proficient at.

> Secondary indexes on Primary datastore
>
> Pros:
>
> 2. Less consistency issues ( because secondary indexes can be eventually consistant)

Not sure what you mean by this. All indexes in an RDBMS are typically immediately consistent, not eventually consistent. I can only envision maybe you mean in a database system with a sharded topology, but that's only because shards can be eventually consistent, but even the indexes within the shard will still be immediately consistent once the shard becomes synchronized.

> Cons
>
> 2. Secondary index queries are more oftan scatter gather, doing it on higher QPS will limit read write qps on primary access patterns like read, write by PK

This is not exactly true. Yes, the more indexes a table has, the more write work that needs to occur to that table to make all of the indexes consistent. But that tradeoff is literally Big O theory - the tradeoff between search time complexity vs space complexity. The same is true, again, if you were to try to copy the data and persist it in another data store like Elasticsearch. There's additional write overhead, just the same.

Also, modern RDBMS offer different concurrency isolation levels, to improve performance. Optimistic concurrency isolation levels improve performance by allowing writes and reads to be able to occur concurrently. Writers don't block readers and readers don't block writers. One implementation of how this is done is via a version store of the data, which the database automatically maintains.

---

Resources:

1. [What is Elasticsearch?](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch)

Comment: Thanks for your descriptive answer. 1. why i meant is if i don't have to support secondary indexes, i could have key value store. 2. you have made very interesting case of being optimized for fuzzy match but not for key value match, Is it possible to share some resource around this? 3. While writing the questions, i was not limiting the choices to RDBMS, but also considering Aerospike, dynamodb where secondary indexes are eventually consistent.

Comment: 4. the point is just trying to highlight that if PK based access pattern is able to do 100 QPS read on 4 boxes, secondary key based lookup might be able to do only 25, since query has to be scatter gather kind (ofcourse there are other considerations like things being cached and all, but the point is that secondary key queries are more costly compared to PK based query (correct me if i am wrong here).

Comment: @bestwishes "*but the point is that secondary key queries are more costly compared to PK based query (correct me if i am wrong here)*" - That's wrong, at least in regards to how RDBMS work (but probably also for other alternative DB systems too). Secondary indexes are structured the same as the primary index, and are literally just a copy of the data sorted on the keys defined in the secondary index. Lookups against those indexes would be no different in QPS than they would against the primary index, for equivalent use cases for each.

Comment: No problem! "*While writing the questions, i was not limiting the choices to RDBMS, but also considering Aerospike, dynamodb where secondary indexes are eventually consistent.*" - Gotcha, you should be more explicit on that next time, as those are the minority in the world of databases, so most people wouldn't realize which systems are being referred to without context.

Comment: "*2. optimized for fuzzy match but not for key value match, Is it possible to share some resource around this?*" - [What is Elasticsearch used for?](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch) lists all full-text search / word search type of problems, none of them are key-value type of problems. Further down in that document, under "Why use Elasticsearch?" it states "*it excels at full-text search*". The whole purpose of Elasticsearch is for word search problems. It has some blend into other areas (like all systems) but it's not as tuned for those other areas. Also, I've used Elasticsearch.